# How to do a wp_query using "BETWEEN" with two meta_values?

Tags: wp-query

I'm starting with Wordpress, already achieved some queries, but this one... ugh! It's being a pain to me!

What i want to do is this part of query:

```
" ... WHERE "VALUE_THAT_I_WANT" BETWEEN event_start_date AND event_end_date ..."
```

Where "event_start_date" and "event_end_date" are meta keys ( i want to use their values, not mine!)

This is what i had so far..

```
$tEA = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => $metaKey,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $postPerPage,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $metaKey,
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => "=",
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_event_end_time'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

```
$tEA = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    // you dont need meta_key as you use meta_query
    //'meta_key' => $metaKey,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $postPerPage,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $metaKey,
            // value should be array of (lower, higher) with BETWEEN
            'value' => array('START_DATE', 'END_DATE'),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    )
);
```

Note that START_DATE and END_DATE should be in MySQL date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: +1 but I'm pretty sure UNIX timestamps are perfectly ok.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks, but as the data type is casted to `DATE`, I am not sure if WP will format it properly while constructing the meta_query, so it is safer to directly use the MySQL date format in this case.

Comment: Ahmad, thanks for the answer, but in my problem 'START_DATE' and 'END_DATE' should be the meta_value of these fields. I have an event that has "_event_start_date" and "_event_end_date", and they are meta_keys.

What i want is do a "BETWEEN" with these two meta_values. I dont want to insert manually the values, because thesse values are meta_values.

Hehe..

Comment: If i do what you saying, look what the query prints:
"BETWEEN '_event_start_date' AND '_event_end_date')"

Answer (score 1):

Didn't [test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) it, but what about this?

```
$tEA = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => $metaKey,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $postPerPage,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date',
            'value' => 'VALUE_THAT_I_WANT',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'event_end_date',
            'value' => 'VALUE_THAT_I_WANT',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_event_end_time'
        )
    )
);
```

I am not sure if you needed the other compare, if you do, just prepend it :P

Comment: in theory should work.. but its not =( I'm trying to fix this. If anyone know how to do it, please, feel free to post it!

Comment: have you tried with only event_start_date array? Why it doesn't work? (no results?)

Comment: Yes, no results. Thats what im talking, in theory, this should work.. but does not! hehe!

Answer (score -1):

Since WP 3.7 you can pass 'date_query' as an argument.

Example that returns posts from January 1st to February 28th:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Code taken from https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: The question is using dates in meta data, not the date field in the posts table.